# Converting Excel cell to percentage using epplus

Tags: c#, epplus

I would like to convert the value in to 2 decimal places. I am using **EPPlus** 
if the value is **66.6666667** and I would like to show it as **66.66%** 
I tried the following code but its not working.

```
   foreach (var dc in dateColumns)
   {
       sheet.Cells[2, dc, rowCount + 1, dc].Style.Numberformat.Format = "###,##%";
   }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found it!

I tried

```
 foreach (var dc in dateColumns)
  {
    sheet.Cells[2, dc, rowCount + 1, dc].Style.Numberformat.Format ="#0\\.00%";
   }
```

Comment: it works when its only "0.00%". so without the '#' and without the '\'. Otherwise the value gets divided by hundred, such that the value stored and the value shown is not the same.

Answer (score 20):

The correct formula is as follows:

```
 foreach (var dc in dateColumns)
  {
    sheet.Cells[2, dc, rowCount + 1, dc].Style.Numberformat.Format ="#0.00%";
  }
```

The Double slash in "#0\\.00%" leads to very unusual numbers when you try to expand the decimal places later

Comment: The only thing is if you already has the value as percentage, you need to divide it by 100 so that its displayed correctly when you open the sheet in excel.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I checked format you set via epp is just a common Excel cell format.

In my case [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/custom-number-format.html) was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on a cells range. You can use

```
using (ExcelRange Rng = wsDashboard.Cells["B6:J6"])
{
    Rng.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#0\\.00%";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet.Cells[1, 1, row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = "##0.00\\%;[Red]-##0.00\\%";
```

It's worked for me.