# How to format decimal numbers as percentage in excel using epplus?

Tags: c#, excel, percentage, epplus

I'm using following code to format decimal number as percentage in excel using Epplus. I have used this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284341/2134604).

```
sheet.Cells["B:B"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#0\\.00%";
```

The number is looking normal in sheets, but in edit bar number is looking different.

**The number 9.47% is showing as 947 in edit bar.**

Check the image for problem sample. How to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem.  Just set the format  to #0.00%.  Put 0.0947 on the edit bar and see what you get.

Comment: Your code displays `9.47` = `947%` as `9.47%` using some artificial custom formatting trick. If you want to have `9.47%` value in your cell, you should divide it by `100`, and format as `"0%"`

Comment: @user3964075 i'm placing decimal value 9.47 in cell, after that i'm formatting with my code.

Comment: @cup if we are using this in excel directly its working, but in excel generated by epplus its not working.

Comment: But you can't change cell's value with formatting. `9.47`=`947%` and that's what formula bar will show. If you want it to be `9.47%` you should place `0.0947` in cell and format `"0.00%"` to have percentage with 2 decimal places.

Comment: @user3964075 oh ok. then please tell me how to append % symbol alone in cell.

Comment: `"0.00\%"` appends `%`. But formula bar wil still show `9.47` and not `9.47%`

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: divide the numbers by 100 and use the following custom format 0.00%